# Iphone version support requirements

Tags: ios

My ios app is designed for iphone 5 and up.  Will my app still be approved if it does not work on iphone 4s, assuming it would be approved at all?

Comment: If your app has memory issues (e.g. memory leak), fix it. It does not relate to App Store requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement that your app work on older devices, but you cannot prevent it from being loaded on older devices either - for example, you cannot specify "iPhone 5 or later". You can require a *system* (i.e. iOS 7).

Comment: Will it still be approved if it works on, say iphone 5, but does not work on iphone 4?

Comment: It might be approved if they don't test and discover the problem, but iPhone 4 users will be able to download it, and if it crashes, that will not be good for you.

Comment: Just loading it on a 3.5 inch screen will make it unplayable as the interface just cant fit on that screensize; resizing is not the issue, the interface just wont work.

Comment: They might notice that and refuse the app. You cannot require the 4 inch screen.

Comment: What a pain.  Its a huge program, too, so retrofitting will be a major hassle.  I guess I'll get more playtesting time.

Comment: What you want to do makes sense to me, but I don't think they will let you do it. This business with the two screen sizes has not proceeded very wisely, in my opinion. The interface must work on the small screen, so on the large screen, by definition, there is usually wasted space.